# Convert a Git folder to a submodule retrospectively?

Tags: git, git-submodules

Quite often it is the case that you're writing a project of some kind, and after a while it becomes clear that some component of the project is actually useful as a standalone component (a library, perhaps). If you've had that idea from early on, then there's a fair chance that most of that code is in its own folder.

Is there a way to convert one of the sub directories in a Git project to a submodule?

Ideally this would happen such that all of the code in that directory is removed from the parent project, and the submodule project is added in its place, with all the appropriate history, and such that all the parent project commits point to the correct submodule commits.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365541/how-to-move-files-from-one-git-repo-to-another-not-a-clone-preserving-history may help some :)

Comment: This is not part of the original question, but what would be even cooler would be a way to keep the history of files that had started outside the folder, and were moved into it. At the moment, all of the answers lose all of the history prior to the move.

Comment: @ggll's link is down. [Here's an archived copy.](https://web.archive.org/web/20161018180354/http://will.willandorla.com/extract-to-git-submodule)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

To isolate a subdirectory into its own repository, use `filter-branch` on a clone of the original repository:

```
git clone <your_project> <your_submodule>
cd <your_submodule>
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter 'path/to/your/submodule' --prune-empty -- --all
```

It's then nothing more than deleting your original directory and adding the submodule to your parent project.

Comment: You probably also want to `git remote rm <name>` after the filter branch, and then perhaps add a new remote. Also, if there are ignored files, a `git clean -xd -f` may be useful

Comment: `-- --all` can be replaced with the name of a branch if the submodule should only be extracted from this branch.

Comment: Does `git clone <your_project> <your_submodule>` only download files for your_submodule?

Comment: @DominicTobias: `git clone source destination` simply tells Git the location of where to put your cloned files. The actual magic to filter your submodule's files then happens in the `filter-branch` step.

Comment: `filter-branch` is [deprecated](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_warning) nowadays. You can use [`git clone --filter`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository/52269934#52269934), but your Git server must be configured to allow filtering, otherwise you'll get `warning: filtering not recognized by server, ignoring`.

Comment: @MatthiasBraun: thanks, I didn't know about the `--filter` option to `git clone`. But nowhere in your linked warning (or the page in which it is contained) does it mention anything of being _deprecated_. But yes, nevertheless, `filter-branch` can be a dangerous command.

Comment: I used "deprecated" in the sense that `filter-branch` shouldn't be used according to the Git developers ("its use is not recommended"). I didn't mean to imply that `filter-branch` will be removed from Git.

Comment: How to use `git clone --filter` to get the same result? @MatthiasBraun

Comment: This command gives me "WARNING: git-filter-branch has a glut of gotchas generating mangled history rewrites...." What's the non-deprecated way to do this? Maybe with this https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/

Comment: When I did this I had a load of ref changes but all of the directories I wanted to filter out were still there?

Comment: @Stefan all directories which are _not_ listed on the command line are removed. Only the one directory which is listed is kept

Comment: @knittl, not when I tried it.  They were still there.  Is there another step I need to take here?

Comment: @Stefan no, normally not. Have you executed the command exactly as written in the answer? Were there any errors? Have you provided the correct refs to be rewritten?

Answer (score 46):

First change dir to folder which will be a submodule. Then:

```
git init
git remote add origin <repourl>
git add .
git commit -am 'first commit in submodule'
git push -u origin master
cd ..
rm -rf <folder> # the folder which will be a submodule
git commit -am 'deleting folder'
git submodule add <repourl> <folder> # add the submodule
git commit -am 'adding submodule'
```

Comment: This will lose all of the history of that folder.

Comment: history of the folder will be saved in main repository and new commits will save history in submodule

Comment: If you have un-tracked content in the soon-to-be-submodule directory (e.g. content listed in your main repository's `.gitignore`), then the `rm -rf <folder>` will cause it to be lost. Better to `cp <folder> <some_other_absolute_path>` then later, after the `rm -rf`, you can `cp <some_other_absolute_path> <folder>` (and delete it at `<some_other_absolute_path>`).

Answer (score 16):

I know this is an old thread, but the answers here squash any related commits in other branches.

A simple way to clone and keep all those extra branches and commits:

1 - Make sure you have this git alias

```
git config --global alias.clone-branches '! git branch -a | sed -n "/\/HEAD /d; /\/master$/d; /remotes/p;" | xargs -L1 git checkout -t'
```

2 - Clone the remote, pull all branches, change the remote, filter your directory, push

```
git clone git@github.com:user/existing-repo.git new-repo
cd new-repo
git clone-branches
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin git@github.com:user/new-repo.git
git remote -v
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter my_directory/ -- --all
git push --all
git push --tags
```

Comment: My original had a link to a gist instead of embedding the code here on SO

Answer (score 8):

The official git project now recommends using [git-filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo)

```
# install git-filter-repo, see [1] for install via pip, or other OS's.
sudo apt-get install git-filter-repo 

# copy your repo; everything EXCEPT the subdir will be deleted, and the subdir will become root.
# --no-local is required to prevent git from hard linking to files in the original, and is checked by `filter-branch`
git clone working-dir/.git working-dir-copy --no-local
cd working-dir-copy

# extract the desired subdirectory and its history.
git filter-repo --subdirectory-filter foodir

# foodir is now its own directory. Push it to github/gitlab etc
git remote add origin user@hosting/project.git
git push -u origin --all
git push -u origin --tags
```

Thanks to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/amomin/b0df11ac4607f15203ac) as well.

EDIT: For LFS users (poor folks) git clone does NOT pull the entire lfs history of an image, which causes git push to fail.

```
// Original branch needs to get history of all images
git lfs fetch --all

// clone needs to copy the history
git lfs install --skip-smudge
git lfs pull working-dir --all
```

https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/INSTALL.md

Comment: This works pretty well. To replace in the original repo: `rm -rf  <subdir>` - `git add .` - `git commit -m 'removed subdir'` - `git submodule add <submodule> <subdir>`

Answer (score 5):

## Status quo

Let's assume we have a repository called `repo-old` which contains a sub**directory** `sub` that we would like to convert into a sub**module** with its own repo `repo-sub`.

It is further intended that the original repo `repo-old` should be converted into a modified repo `repo-new` where all commits touching the previously existing subdirectory `sub` shall now point to the corresponding commits of our extracted submodule repo `repo-sub`.

## Let's change

It is possible to achieve this with the help of `git filter-branch` in a two step process:

1. Subdirectory extraction from `repo-old` to `repo-sub` (already mentioned in the accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12515629/13613140))
2. Subdirectory replacement from `repo-old` to `repo-new` (with proper commit mapping)

**Remark**: I know that this question is old and it has already been mentioned that `git filter-branch` is kind of deprecated and might be dangerous. But on the other hand it might help others with personal repositories that are easy to validate after conversion. So be **warned**! And please let me know if there is any other tool that does the same thing without being deprecated and is safe to use!

I'll explain how I realized both steps on linux with git version 2.26.2 below. Older versions might work to some extend but that needs to be tested.

For the sake of simplicity I will restrict myself to the case where there is just a `master` branch and a `origin` remote in the original repo `repo-old`. Also be warned that I rely on temporary git tags with the prefix `temp_` which are going to be removed in the process. So if there are already tags named similarily you might want to adjust the prefix below. And finally please be aware that I have not extensively tested this and there might be corner cases where the recipe fails. So please **backup everything before proceeding**!

The following bash snippets can be concatenated into one big script which should then be executed in the same folder where the repo `repo-org` lives. It is not recommended to copy and paste everything directly into a command window (even though I have tested this successfully)!

### 0. Preparation

#### Variables

```sh
# Root directory where repo-org lives
# and a temporary location for git filter-branch
root="$PWD"
temp='/dev/shm/tmp'

# The old repository and the subdirectory we'd like to extract
repo_old="$root/repo-old"
repo_old_directory='sub'

# The new submodule repository, its url
# and a hash map folder which will be populated
# and later used in the filter script below
repo_sub="$root/repo-sub"
repo_sub_url='https://github.com/somewhere/repo-sub.git'
repo_sub_hashmap="$root/repo-sub.map"

# The new modified repository, its url
# and a filter script which is created as heredoc below
repo_new="$root/repo-new"
repo_new_url='https://github.com/somewhere/repo-new.git'
repo_new_filter="$root/repo-new.sh"
```

#### Filter script

```sh
# The index filter script which converts our subdirectory into a submodule
cat << EOF > "$repo_new_filter"
#!/bin/bash

# Submodule hash map function
sub ()
{
    local old_commit=\$(git rev-list -1 \$1 -- '$repo_old_directory')

    if [ ! -z "\$old_commit" ]
    then
        echo \$(cat "$repo_sub_hashmap/\$old_commit")
    fi
}

# Submodule config
SUB_COMMIT=\$(sub \$GIT_COMMIT)
SUB_DIR='$repo_old_directory'
SUB_URL='$repo_sub_url'

# Submodule replacement
if [ ! -z "\$SUB_COMMIT" ]
then
    touch '.gitmodules'
    git config --file='.gitmodules' "submodule.\$SUB_DIR.path" "\$SUB_DIR"
    git config --file='.gitmodules' "submodule.\$SUB_DIR.url" "\$SUB_URL"
    git config --file='.gitmodules' "submodule.\$SUB_DIR.branch" 'master'
    git add '.gitmodules'

    git rm --cached -qrf "\$SUB_DIR"
    git update-index --add --cacheinfo 160000 \$SUB_COMMIT "\$SUB_DIR"
fi
EOF
chmod +x "$repo_new_filter"
```

### 1. Subdirectory extraction

```sh
cd "$root"

# Create a new clone for our new submodule repo
git clone "$repo_old" "$repo_sub"

# Enter the new submodule repo
cd "$repo_sub"

# Remove the old origin remote
git remote remove origin

# Loop over all commits and create temporary tags
for commit in $(git rev-list --all)
do
    git tag "temp_$commit" $commit
done

# Extract the subdirectory and slice commits
mkdir -p "$temp"
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter "$repo_old_directory" \
                  --tag-name-filter 'cat' \
                  --prune-empty --force -d "$temp" -- --all

# Populate hash map folder from our previously created tag names
mkdir -p "$repo_sub_hashmap"
for tag in $(git tag | grep "^temp_")
do
    old_commit=${tag#'temp_'}
    sub_commit=$(git rev-list -1 $tag)

    echo $sub_commit > "$repo_sub_hashmap/$old_commit"
done
git tag | grep "^temp_" | xargs -d '\n' git tag -d 2>&1 > /dev/null

# Add the new url for this repository (and e.g. push)
git remote add origin "$repo_sub_url"
# git push -u origin master
```

### 2. Subdirectory replacement

```sh
cd "$root"

# Create a clone for our modified repo
git clone "$repo_old" "$repo_new"

# Enter the new modified repo
cd "$repo_new"

# Remove the old origin remote
git remote remove origin

# Replace the subdirectory and map all sliced submodule commits using
# the filter script from above
mkdir -p "$temp"
git filter-branch --index-filter "$repo_new_filter" \
                  --tag-name-filter 'cat' --force -d "$temp" -- --all

# Add the new url for this repository (and e.g. push)
git remote add origin "$repo_new_url"
# git push -u origin master

# Cleanup (commented for safety reasons)
# rm -rf "$repo_sub_hashmap"
# rm -f "$repo_new_filter"
```

**Remark:** If the newly created repo `repo-new` hangs during `git submodule update --init` then try to re-clone the repository recursively once instead:

```sh
cd "$root"

# Clone the new modified repo recursively
git clone --recursive "$repo_new" "$repo_new-tmp"

# Now use the newly cloned one
mv "$repo_new" "$repo_new-bak"
mv "$repo_new-tmp" "$repo_new"

# Cleanup (commented for safety reasons)
# rm -rf "$repo_new-bak"
```

Comment: This is an amazing answer. Exactly what I needed, and clearly outlines the steps needed, in an easy to follow format.

Comment: Fantastic guide - than you very much.

Answer (score 2):

The current answer by @knittl using `filter-branch` gets us quite close to the desired effect, but when tried, Git threw a warning at me:

```
WARNING: git-filter-branch has a glut of gotchas generating mangled history
         rewrites.  Hit Ctrl-C before proceeding to abort, then use an
         alternative filtering tool such as 'git filter-repo'
         (https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/) instead.  See the
         filter-branch manual page for more details; to squelch this warning,
         set FILTER_BRANCH_SQUELCH_WARNING=1.
```

Now 9 years after this question was first asked and answered, `filter-branch` is deprecated in favor of `git filter-repo`. Indeed, when I looked at my git history using `git log --all --oneline --graph`, it was full of irrelevant commits.

How to use [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) then? Github has a pretty good article outlining that [here](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/using-git/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository). (Note that you will need to install it independently from git. I used the python version with `pip3 install git-filter-repo`)

In case they decide to move/delete the article, I will summarize and generalize their procedure below:

```
git clone <your_old_project_remote> <your_submodule>
cd <your_submodule>
git filter-repo --path path/to/your/submodule
git remote set-url origin <your_new_submodule_remote>
git push -u origin <branch_name>
```

From there, you just need to register the new repository as a submodule where you want it to be:

```
cd <path/to/your/parent/module>
git submodule add <your_new_submodule_remote>
git submodule update
git commit
```

Comment: This leaves the code in the same sub directory (path/to/your/submodule) also in the new repo. How to let the sub directory in the old repo be the top-level directory in the new one (without simply moving it after the filtering is done)?

Comment: `git filter-repo --subdirectory-filter path/to/your/submodule` seems to have done the trick

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, but it's not simple. If you search for `git filter-branch`, `subdirectory` and `submodule`, there are some decent write-ups on the process. It essentially entails creating two clones of your project, using `git filter-branch` to remove everything except the one subdirectory in one, and removing only that subdirectory in the other. Then you can establish the second repository as a submodule of the first.

Answer (score 0):

This does the conversion in-place, you can back it out as you would any filter-branch (I use `git fetch . +refs/original/*:*`).

I have a project with a `utils` library that's started to be useful in other projects, and wanted to split its history off into a submodules.  Didn't think to look on SO first so I wrote my own, it builds the history locally so it's a good bit faster, after which if you want you can set up the helper command's `.gitmodules` file and such, and push the submodule histories themselves anywhere you want.

The stripped command itself is here, the doc's in the comments, in the unstripped one that follows.  Run it as its own command, with `subdir` set, like `subdir=utils git split-submodule` if you're splitting the `utils` directory.  It's hacky because it's a one-off, but I tested it on the Documentation subdirectory in the Git history.

```
#!/bin/bash
# put this or the commented version below in e.g. ~/bin/git-split-submodule
${GIT_COMMIT-exec git filter-branch --index-filter "subdir=$subdir; ${debug+debug=$debug;} $(sed 1,/SNIP/d "$0")" "$@"}
${debug+set -x}
fam=(`git rev-list --no-walk --parents $GIT_COMMIT`)
pathcheck=(`printf "%s:$subdir\\n" ${fam[@]} \
    | git cat-file --batch-check='%(objectname)' | uniq`)
[[ $pathcheck = *:* ]] || {
    subfam=($( set -- ${fam[@]}; shift;
        for par; do tpar=`map $par`; [[ $tpar != $par ]] &&
            git rev-parse -q --verify $tpar:"$subdir"
        done
    ))
    git rm -rq --cached --ignore-unmatch  "$subdir"
    if (( ${#pathcheck[@]} == 1 && ${#fam[@]} > 1 && ${#subfam[@]} > 0)); then
        git update-index --add --cacheinfo 160000,$subfam,"$subdir"
    else
        subnew=`git cat-file -p $GIT_COMMIT | sed 1,/^$/d \
            | git commit-tree $GIT_COMMIT:"$subdir" $(
                ${subfam:+printf ' -p %s' ${subfam[@]}}) 2>&-
            ` &&
        git update-index --add --cacheinfo 160000,$subnew,"$subdir"
    fi
}
${debug+set +x}
```

---

```
#!/bin/bash
# Git filter-branch to split a subdirectory into a submodule history.

# In each commit, the subdirectory tree is replaced in the index with an
# appropriate submodule commit.
# * If the subdirectory tree has changed from any parent, or there are
#   no parents, a new submodule commit is made for the subdirectory (with
#   the current commit's message, which should presumably say something
#   about the change). The new submodule commit's parents are the
#   submodule commits in any rewrites of the current commit's parents.
# * Otherwise, the submodule commit is copied from a parent.

# Since the new history includes references to the new submodule
# history, the new submodule history isn't dangling, it's incorporated.
# Branches for any part of it can be made casually and pushed into any
# other repo as desired, so hooking up the `git submodule` helper
# command's conveniences is easy, e.g.
#     subdir=utils git split-submodule master
#     git branch utils $(git rev-parse master:utils)
#     git clone -sb utils . ../utilsrepo
# and you can then submodule add from there in other repos, but really,
# for small utility libraries and such, just fetching the submodule
# histories into your own repo is easiest. Setup on cloning a
# project using "incorporated" submodules like this is:
#   setup:  utils/.git
#
#   utils/.git:
#       @if _=`git rev-parse -q --verify utils`; then \
#           git config submodule.utils.active true \
#           && git config submodule.utils.url "`pwd -P`" \
#           && git clone -s . utils -nb utils \
#           && git submodule absorbgitdirs utils \
#           && git -C utils checkout $$(git rev-parse :utils); \
#       fi
# with `git config -f .gitmodules submodule.utils.path utils` and
# `git config -f .gitmodules submodule.utils.url ./`; cloners don't
# have to do anything but `make setup`, and `setup` should be a prereq
# on most things anyway.

# You can test that a commit and its rewrite put the same tree in the
# same place with this function:
# testit ()
# {
#     tree=($(git rev-parse `git rev-parse $1`: refs/original/refs/heads/$1));
#     echo $tree `test $tree != ${tree[1]} && echo ${tree[1]}`
# }
# so e.g. `testit make~95^2:t` will print the `t` tree there and if
# the `t` tree at ~95^2 from the original differs it'll print that too.

# To run it, say `subdir=path/to/it git split-submodule` with whatever
# filter-branch args you want.

# $GIT_COMMIT is set if we're already in filter-branch, if not, get there:
${GIT_COMMIT-exec git filter-branch --index-filter "subdir=$subdir; ${debug+debug=$debug;} $(sed 1,/SNIP/d "$0")" "$@"}

${debug+set -x}
fam=(`git rev-list --no-walk --parents $GIT_COMMIT`)
pathcheck=(`printf "%s:$subdir\\n" ${fam[@]} \
    | git cat-file --batch-check='%(objectname)' | uniq`)

[[ $pathcheck = *:* ]] || {
    subfam=($( set -- ${fam[@]}; shift;
        for par; do tpar=`map $par`; [[ $tpar != $par ]] &&
            git rev-parse -q --verify $tpar:"$subdir"
        done
    ))

    git rm -rq --cached --ignore-unmatch  "$subdir"
    if (( ${#pathcheck[@]} == 1 && ${#fam[@]} > 1 && ${#subfam[@]} > 0)); then
        # one id same for all entries, copy mapped mom's submod commit
        git update-index --add --cacheinfo 160000,$subfam,"$subdir"
    else
        # no mapped parents or something changed somewhere, make new
        # submod commit for current subdir content.  The new submod
        # commit has all mapped parents' submodule commits as parents:
        subnew=`git cat-file -p $GIT_COMMIT | sed 1,/^$/d \
            | git commit-tree $GIT_COMMIT:"$subdir" $(
                ${subfam:+printf ' -p %s' ${subfam[@]}}) 2>&-
            ` &&
        git update-index --add --cacheinfo 160000,$subnew,"$subdir"
    fi
}
${debug+set +x}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's acceptable to keep the previous history in the *parent folder only*, a simple solution is removing the [subfolder from the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30360954/5362795) and starting a new repository or submodule in the same path. For example:

1. Add `subdir` to `.gitignore`
2. `rm -r --cached subdir`
3. `git add .gitignore && git commit`
4. `cd subdir && git init && git add .`
5. Commit initial files in the new `subdir` repository

From `git help rm`:

> --cached:
> Use this option to unstage and remove paths only from the index. Working tree files, whether modified or not, will be left alone.

Having used [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) in production code, I can say that it's a nice solution, especially since it documents the project's dependencies.

For a simple project, or if there aren't other developers, or there isn't a strong dependency and the folder structure is more of a convenience, submodules may be a little too much. If you choose to go that route however, skip step 1 and proceed accordingly.