# I copy/pasted/modified a dependency in my project. This was not a smart dependency management strategy. How do I step back?

Tags: c++, git, dependencies, git-submodules, git-subtree

## Context:

`MainProject` depends on a header-only dependency `Module`.

Both `MainProject` and `Module` are:

- still under development and **subject to modifications**
- modern CMake projects
- independent repositories on Github
- controlled by me

## Problem:

Few months before, I tried without success to manage this dependency using CMake and versioning. Pressed by deadlines, I ended up opting for the *"simplest solution"* to copy-paste project `Module` headers in `MainProject`. Developing `MainProject` led to add features and modify interfaces in the `Module` **local copy**. Now there are two diverging `Module`.

## How it could have worked

- It could have worked if `Module` was very stable (copy/pasting headers is actually the solution I opted for dependencies that are stable and for which I don't have ownership).
- I could have modified/commited/pushed/recopy/repasted the `Module` repository for every modification I wanted to bring. But of course I did not because ... time and deadlines.

## Question

Now I would like to step back from this solution (*ie*, reflect the modifications on the initial `Module` project) and chose a better dependency management strategy.

## What I can think of

- create a new branch `update` on `Module` git project, copy-paste the modified version, commit it and use `git diff` to check the differences with branch `master`
- use one or a combination of these three approaches (but I don't know how to chose)

  - **git submodules**
  - **git subtrees**
  - **C++20 modules**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Module` project literally *is* a Git submodule: an independently-updated history, from which your `MainProject` builds use specific revisions.

> Developing `MainProject` led to add features and modify interfaces in the `Module` local copy. Now there are two diverging `Module`

Quickest: from a clean checkout of your current `MainProject` revision,

```
git tag slice $(git commit-tree -m slice @:path/to/Module)
git rm -rf path/to/Module
git submodule add u://r/l path/to/Module
git push path/to/Module slice
cd path/to/Module
git read-tree -um slice
git commit -m 'Module content from MainProject'
```

and now you've got your content and ancestry looking serviceable, and you can add labels and push it wherever it needs to go, e.g. `git checkout -b MainProjectModule; git push -u origin MainProjectModule`

If you've got a long history of `Module` changes in your main project that you want to preserve in the `Module` history proper, it's doable, and even fairly efficient, but you'll need to adapt [some history surgery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54797306/1290731) to achieve it, instead of tagging a nonce commit, tag the submodule commit that command produces and merge that rather than just adding its tip content as a new commit.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it points me towards a direction. I am not sure I follow the sequence of git commands and what they are intended for. Would you mind precising ? From what I understand, you create a tag to remember the current state, then you delete the module folder, then you create the submodule. At this point it contains the naive remote state. So somehow you tell it to retrieve the state of the previously deleted folder. Am I right ? I don't get the `git push path/to/Module slice` and the `git read-tree -um slice` command. Thanks again :)

Comment: The push pushes that ref, the tag (of just that one no-ancestry commit of just that tree), to the (freshly-cloned) repository at path. The `git read-tree -um` is the core command underlying checkout, it does only the index and work tree changes.