# Can you exclude files on pull requests?

Tags: git, github

Is there a way to limit the files that a new developer coming on the team can pull from a Github repository? I may not want a new developer to be able to see/clone the entire project.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Size of the repo? Not everything beoing open source?

Comment: What if you are developing a project and collaborating with people you have never met in person. They get the repo and launch your site!

Answer (score 1):

A git repository isn't a file storage, but a database of code, patches and metadata.

You can filter what files you pull from a repository, but then, nothing would prevent to have access to other files in this subdirectory.

Outside the Git world, to have such by directory ACL control, Subversion is still interesting:
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html

In the Git world, what you can do is:

1. to have several Git repositories, one by project component. So you'll be able to give your developer access to a small repository with only the relevant code.
2. to organize these repositories for your project into a main repository, with subrepositories. Git has a feature to achieve that, called submodules — http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

To prepare these submodules from your current repository, you can use the `git filter-branch` command. See the question https://stackoverflow.com/a/12515629/1930997 to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

No, git does not track any permissions. There is only one way of controlling access to a git repository: Using the unix permission system.

This basically means that there are only 3 possible access levels to a git repo:
- Not at all
- Full read access
- Full write access

CodeGnome suggested using submodules. These will allow you to put some of your code into a separate repo, which can have different permissions than the main repo.