# Splitting out a sub directory in a git repo into it's own repo

Tags: git, github, refactoring, git-submodules, git-subtree

I have the following structure:

```
 my_main_project/
    my_lib/
       file1
       dir2/
           file2
    my_other_files
```

And now, the `my_lib` has got to the point where it really should be it's own library, and should be a submodule in `my_main_project`

IE:

```
my_main_project/  (is repo)
    <my_lib>  (is sub module)
    my_other_files/

my_lib/ (is repo)
    file1
    dir2/
    file2
```

I ideally wish to keep the git history for `my_lib` for obvious reasons.

Anyway, I tried the following: [Convert a git folder to a submodule retrospectively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514197)

However, it fielded this error

```
$ git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter '../my_main_project/my_lib' --prune-empty -- --all
> fatal '../my_main_project/my_lib' is outside repository
```

What, am I doing wrong and what needs to be done to get this working. I should point out that my_main_project is on branch master, and that is the branch of the subdir I wish to port.

Please let me know if there is an supplementary information you need.

Comment: Why the path to the subdirectory is `../my_main_project/my_lib`, are you running the command from outside the main project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `path/to/your/submodule` from the post you linked to is the path to the submodule directory in your **cloned repository** (the new one in which you should be when executing this command) not in the original one. Judging by what you wrote it should be just `my_lib`

```
$ git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter 'my_lib' --prune-empty -- --all
```