# git rm --cached not removing files from tracking

Tags: git

I want to stop tracking a data.pkl file, which is too large to push to github.

I've used "git rm --cached data.pkl" to remove tracking according to [Remove a folder from git tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24290358/remove-a-folder-from-git-tracking)

I used "git ls-tree -r master --name-only" to check what files are tracked. I found data.pkl shows in the list. Even I did git rm --cached -r ., I still see all files being tracked.

Below screenshot shows the .pkl I want to stop tracking already in "delete mode". But once I do push, these files are resulting in a push failure.

[image]

Comment: `git ls-tree -r master --name-only` output content of commit pointed by `master`. `git rm --cached data.pkl` only modify index and not affect any existing commit or reference.

Comment: Then how can I check whether I've stop tracking data.pkl? @PetSerAI

Comment: Point of Git is to preserve your entire history. Untracking file do not remove it from history. To remove file from your history, you need to rewrite your history.

Comment: I'm running into this same issue, is there a way to remove this reference to the large file?? right now I can't push my changes to github. I have deleted the file locally, deleted it from github respository and used the git rm --cache filename ...but somehow it's still complaining about htis large file