# .gitignore is not working properly

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm running a website and I deployed Git for file versioning to keep track of edited files... I noticed that even cache files are pushed to Gitlab which I don't want.

I created a .gitignore file and put a line like this:

/app/cache/dev/smarty/compile/*

I added it, committed and pushed it, Life is beautiful.

Now, everytime I do : git status, I see these files as modified which are browsing cache

```
 modified:   app/cache/dev/smarty/compile/00/7c/14/007c1437400d132932e061d38915162f50f3b8d7.file.ApProductList.tpl.php
    modified:   app/cache/dev/smarty/compile/11/0e/c7/110ec72aa9921d2c382ad628bdb2f0bc5105a617.module.ps_searchbar.tpl.php
    modified:   app/cache/dev/smarty/compile/14/cf/62/14cf62b857ae9d1a45052e93e4a5f7744c543c46.file.ApMegamenu.tpl.php
    modified:   app/cache/dev/smarty/compile/15/9c/65/159c651fcb923e7ff3efcd17bc6356e6f77d1032.file.leoslideshow.tpl.php
    modified:   app/cache/dev/smarty/compile/18/2a/ea/182aea6706a2d4ae5bfc3f6d3a5b33417c49b6af.module.notification.tpl.php
    modified:   app/cache/dev/smarty/compile/24/41/64/24416476c1e4c535f73ed4c66a125c0e880f294b.file.leo_list_product_review.tpl.php
    modified:   app/cache/dev/smarty/compile/30/7d/c6/307dc6bd4724d29d1572cc301dd7148e962604ef.module.ps_emailsubscription.tpl.php
    modified:   app/cache/dev/smarty/compile/32/74/ea/3274eac0d659ac48de29176349457a485f0a7846.file.ApBlockLink.tpl.php
    modified:   app/cache/dev/smarty/compile/35/65/5e/35655e6409b6198f29dd6e732ef9598dec599880.module.ps_shoppingcart.tpl.php
    modified:   app/cache/dev/smarty/compile/38/37/a8/3837a8fdc3367fa8be15dd17f53842319311023b.file.plist1487280701.tpl.php
    modified:   app/cache/dev/smarty/compile/39/e1/75/39e175b351bd73dee402d5a54877d3be6344bbe4.file.leo_cart_button.tpl.php
    modified:   app/cache/dev/smarty/compile/3b/2b/08/3b2b08f3e7cd22b2aad86e184d6bdfdc8b3802cf.module.modal.tpl.php
    modified:   app/cache/dev/smarty/compile/43/80/cd/4380cd32bf825479f4e58e8f1a26818a8f607913.file.ApHtml.tpl.php
    modified:   app/cache/dev/smarty/compile/51/3e/9c/513e9ce13e7d8790fecede8bcf00cdc8ca0ef171.file.slidecaptcha-header.tpl.php
    modified:   app/cache/dev/smarty/compile/5a/51/17/5a5117cf6d0e1dffe864e8c6e12c7c631b3df555.file.ApColumn.tpl.php
    modified:   app/cache/dev/smarty/compile/5e/b2/05/5eb205658affb81ad209afd041b5ce7f724c9288.file.appagebuilder.tpl.php
    modified:   app/cache/dev/smarty/compile/75/be/84/75be842c1b804d7817967aceea1b33cc9f212c84.file.ApModule.tpl.php
    modified:   app/cache/dev/smarty/compile/80/5c/e2/805ce2d86f1187d802d55b829fd8b831e391ad7c.module.fly_cart.tpl.php
    modified:   app/cache/dev/smarty/compile/80/ac/9d/80ac9ddb06fe7b43ffdd2f5cd1185536480d2577.module.ps_socialfollow.tpl.php
    modified:   app/cache/dev/smarty/compile/8d/87/67/8d87672f84fea39023a026ec3e77c50d0205b84a.file.megamenu.tpl.php
    modified:   app/cache/dev/smarty/compile/94/3d/87/943d870759e124a38846d736284d297b82268471.file.ApSlideShow.tpl.php
    modified:   app/cache/dev/smarty/compile/97/9d/97/979d976ed6034e059eef22b8e951012b4262674e.file.ApManuFacturersCarousel.tpl.php
    modified:   app/cache/dev/smarty/compile/99/f1/47/99f147cdc5f8fa7776be7f182bac4542c4e7954c.file.ApProductCarousel.tpl.php
    modified:   app/cache/dev/smarty/compile/9d/30/9b/9d309b84d5f56fc52e6632a8d91893c2f5a67658.file.javascript_parameter.tpl.php
```

it's a long list, how to stop pushing those file by ignoring them, I might forgot to do something?

Comment: try the command git rm --cached -r <files>

Comment: If these specific files were being tracked and committed before you added the gitignore then you can delete them manually and push that as a commit. They won't show up after that.

Comment: Apparently [Git is ignoring you, not your files](http://axiac.ro/blog/git-ignores-me-not-my-files/). Or maybe not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Answer (score 4):

Adding files to `.gitignore` does not remove them from the repository. It just prevents `git add` from adding these files as new files.

So after adding `/app/cache/dev/smarty/compile/*` to `.gitignore`, you also have to remove these files from your repository, preferably without removing them from the filesystem to not disrupt your website.

To do this, you can execute `git rm --cached -r app/cache/dev/smarty/compile/*`, check the result that it only removes the files you want removed and commit it.

Comment: that was smart and like charm! Thanks alot

Comment: Should I remove the asterisk as others are saying?

Comment: It depends on personal taste, technically it makes no difference in this case as far as I can see. Removing the asterisk tells git to ignore the directory and its contents, leaving the asterisk in place tells git to ignore all files and directories in the directory. As git only tracks files and not directories, both result in the exact same set of actually ignored files.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to update your `.gitignore` to match all sub-directories of `/app/cache/dev/smarty/compile` by removing the trailing asterisk.

Then, you need to clean up the files that have already been added to the repository in earlier commits of the branch. You can do so by running `git rm -r app/cache/dev/smarty/compile`. Once they are removed from your branch, they should not appear anymore when running `git status`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a description of gitignore pattern format: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format

In your case /app/cache/dev/smarty/compile/ without asterics should work.

But gitignore won't help once your files are tracked (if they are in modified section this means that they are tracked). This answer should help you to remove them from tracked: [Remove a folder from git tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24290358/remove-a-folder-from-git-tracking)