# VS Code Git, 3000+ commits

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I recently installed VS code on Ubuntu, and when trying to set up Git, I realized that all changes to my files are registered as changes in a Git repository, leading to me having to commit any changes to any file that is augmented on my device, such as cache files from Google Chrome.

This leads to over [3371 commits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMhFK.png) that I have to accept every time I open another document and files that I am actually using get lost in this mush of files.

[image: files versioned]

The *specific* problem is: How can I avoid having to version *all* my files?
(which is why I see all those "changes" in VSCode Source Control section)

Comment: are you storing your entire home directory in a git repo?

Comment: I'm not sure, but if I am, how would I fix that?

Comment: Are u sure you `git init` or `git clone` in proper folder?

Comment: ahh, I just checked, yes my entire user directory is a get repo...

Comment: I just removed the folder from git tracking, so hopefully that will fix the problem

Comment: In future `mkdir {repo_name} | cd {repo_name}`  and then `git init`. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, as it turns out, I wasn't able to remove the directory from git tracking after following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24290358/remove-a-folder-from-git-tracking . Is there something else that I can do?

Comment: probably would be a good idea to check out something like this. git can be confusing as all hell sometimes. https://www.atlassian.com/git

Answer (score 2):

> ahh, I just checked, yes my entire user directory is a get repo.

If you have a `~/.git` folder, you should remove it (at at least rename it): there is no good practice recommending to put its *entire* home folder under version control.
Or you should at least have a `.gitignore` file properly configured.

But if you did not explicitly setup that Git repository in `~`, delete it.

Comment: how do I properly configure the .gitignore file? Sorry I'm completely new to this

Comment: @AJLaBarca The point is: you should not need to configure a .gitignore, because you should not have a .git in your home folder in the first place. Sidenote: on .gitignore, see https://www.gitignore.io/ and https://stackoverflow.com/a/467053/6309.