# Is it possible to recover from commiting the .metadata folder of an eclipse based IDE to git?

Tags: eclipse, git

I'm using ST's IDE for STM32 microcontrollers, STM32Cube. It is based on eclipse, just with extra additions for working with microcontrollers. I have made the apparently fatal error of not adding the .metadata folder to the gitignore immediately upon creating the repository. This worked fine until I tried to revert to a previous commit, upon which I got a myriad of random merge conflicts on both text and binary files, mostly in the .metadata folder. I have tried to remove the .metadata folder from the repository, but git stubbornly refuses to ignore it despite using the methods describe in these answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4308645/6181778
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30360954/6181778
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2163926/6181778 (for solving the alleged merge conflicts)

As far as the merge conflicts are concerned, they don't make any sense since I am the only contributor to the repository, so it is impossible for two different versions of a file to be committed. Git has now inserted a bunch of merge conflict stuff (most of which doesn't even have two sections, just a head and tail with no divider) into all my files, and STCube refuses to launch because of it. Is there any way to recover from this, or do I just need to try and salvage my code and start a new repository?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that this happened after reverting to a previous commit.
I suspect that you need to undo that revert first:

git reset --hard commit-before-revert

and then follow the instructions you linked to:

Step 1. Add the folder path to your repo's root .gitignore file.

path_to_your_folder/

Step 2. Remove the folder from your local git tracking, but keep it on your disk.

git rm -r --cached path_to_your_folder/

Step 3. Push your changes to your git repo.

At this point it should be safe to do the revert because git will ignore the .metadata folder now.