# Git rewrite with submodules, absorb submodule files at each commit?

Tags: git

I want to do something a little more complicated than [un-submodule a git submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759587/un-submodule-a-git-submodule)

I have a top-level git repo that contains submodule repos.

I want to perform a filter-branch history rewrite on the top-level repo, and essentially incorporate the files from the corresponding submodule version *at each commit in the top-level history*.

This can also be described as the reverse of [Convert a git folder to a submodule retrospectively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514197/convert-a-git-folder-to-a-submodule-retrospectively)

For example,

Submodule repo has history

```
A--B--C--D
```

Top repo has history

```
X--Y--Z
where
X[points to A]--Y[points to B]--Z[points to D]
```

The naive solution described in the other question would result in:

```
A--B--C--D
          \
           > M
          / 
   X--Y--Z
```

I would like instead:

```
X'--Y'--Z'
where:
X' is X plus the files from A
Y' is Y plus the files from B
Z' is Z plus the files from D'
```

*Addressing comment from user torek: Note that commit C is lost, and commit D' contains all the changes from commits C and D. This is not by choice, but a simplification. I would also be just as happy with a commit C' (the changes from C) just showing up between Y' and Z', unfortunately that introduces other edge cases that are not worth solving for.*

**What have I tried so far?**

Spent some time trying to articulate what I want to do and researching existing SO questions.

**Is this an XY problem?**

No, it's not. This is not part of some larger problem that I'm actually trying to solve.

Comment: Worth noting: if the superproject has, say, 3 unique gitlinks to the submodule, but the submodule itself has more than 3 commits, you will almost certainly omit all but three of the submodule commits in the rewritten, de-submodule-ized superproject. If you wish to avoid that you have a much harder problem as there's no guarantee that the superproject commit graph and submodule commit graph are conformable.

Comment: Yes, good catch. I updated the question to show a lost commit from the submodule repo.

Answer (score 3):

A submodule is a (perfectly ordinary) repository, if you want to read stuff out of its commits you can add its object db to your search.

```
GIT_ALTERNATE_OBJECT_DIRECTORIES=$PWD/.git/modules/mysubmodule/objects \
git filter-branch --index-filter '
        if subcommit=`git rev-parse -q --verify :path/to/submodule`; then
                git update-index --force-remove path/to/submodule
                git read-tree --prefix=path/to/submodule/ $subcommit
        fi
' -- --all
GIT_ALTERNATE_OBJECT_DIRECTORIES=$PWD/.git/modules/mysubmodule/objects \
git repack -ad
```

should do it.

Comment: The `git rev-parse` seems to be failing when executed inside the filter. There is no error message, just a non-zero exit code :-(

Comment: Removing the `-q` option I get... `fatal: Needed a single revision
tree filter failed: git rev-parse --verify :***` where `***` is my submodule path. When I change it back to an `index-filter` the error is the same

Comment: Fixed its behavior when path/to/submodule doesn't exist, sorry for oops.  but where are you getting a tree filter from? this is an index filter.  Ah, I see you were just trying it.

Comment: Yeah sorry I changed the index-filter to a tree-filter while debugging. It's back to an index-filter now.

Comment: Failed halfway on `failed to unpack tree object`... I think there was a deleted commit at some point the submodule's history

Comment: If there was ever a not-a-commit at that path you'll have to add some more to the filter to handle that, e.g. add ``&& [[ `git cat-file -t $subcommit` = commit ]]`` to the test.

Comment: I have it skipping the errors now, I just need to figure out how to have these bad commits dropped from the history