# After converting folder to git submodule, how to easily switch between branches

Tags: git, git-submodules

I recently converted a folder of my git repository to a submodule, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514197/convert-a-git-folder-to-a-submodule-retrospectively). The process works well for the master branch.

However, I've found that when switching to any other branch, I get the following error:
`The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:`, listing all files in the converted folder. The only solution seems to be to manually move/delete the folder, and then switch branches. Once I've merged in the changes from master, this resolves, but I'll still need to switch to branches (or historical commits) where I won't be merging any time soon.

Is there any better way to do this? Or a better way to do the folder-to-submodule conversion that would not require this process?

My primary constraint is that I'd like to avoid rewriting history, since this is a repo shared by many others, who would then need to overwrite their local history.

Comment: So, you want to have submodule **locally** only?

Comment: No, I'd like these changes to be pushed to the remote as well. Is that what you mean? My last comment was just meant to say that rebasing isn't ideal.

Comment: Sounds like a `repo` tool (widely used in Android development).