# two directories in git submodule

Tags: git, github

I have few repos that requre same files in each. I discovered that I can use git submodules to do it but I got stuck.

Let's say this is a file structure in each of my projects:

**MainCatalog/**

1. CatalogA (contains some files)
2. CatalogB (contains some files)
3. CatalogC (contains some files)
4. File1
5. File2
6. ...

And with that structure I'd like to use a submodule for two catalogs (CatalogA and CatalogB)
Is it possible? Or should I use two submodules for each catalog?

Comment: Two solutions two submodules, or one submodule and symlink to have your directory structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use git submodules. You just have to see/decide if `CatalogA` and `CatalogB` should be in separate repositories.

Since you want these two catalogues to be a submodule, they have to either have separate or one joint git repo.

After that, you only need to add them as a submodule to your projects, like so:

```
git submodule add https://github.com/<you>/CatalogAandCatalogB

# or if they are in separate repos

git submodule add https://github.com/<you>/CatalogA
git submodule add https://github.com/<you>/CatalogB
```

*Note:* if in your project you already have `CatalogA` and `CatalogB`, then you can transform your subfolders into submodules easily. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514197/convert-a-git-folder-to-a-submodule-retrospectively) covers the topic nicely!